# Forcing UART for wireless operations

Tags: networking, wireless-networking

I'm using **XBee** with an **UART** device powered by ON/SLEEP pin.

The problem is that whenever I connect my **XBee** to the device it forces **SPI** connection and according to the manual that is because I'm asserting **DOUT** low during reset, but maybe that is because the device is waiting for power up.

When forcing **SPI** the pins D1,D2,D3,D4 and P2 get changed to SPI parameters and I cannot revert to Disable because of Status Error (wirelessly)

Is possible to force **UART** operation wirelessly after SPI operation was forced?

I'm Using **XBee 900HP** with firmware **8072**.

Comment: Simple google search will answer your question.

Comment: Looks like this question is copied from the source which is below.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**DOUT** is suppose to be controlled by the radio and not your device. If your device is holding it low, then that is an issue. It should be floating.

[Source:](http://www.digi.com/support/forum/53696/forcing-uart-operation-wirelessly)